# PresentViewController with custom size

Tags: ios, swift

I have this old code in objective-c that present a view controller inside my current view in a custom frame:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController;

    viewController = nil;
    PopoverChoiseTableViewController *viewControllers = (PopoverChoiseTableViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modalPopoverChoise"];

    viewController = viewControllers;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{
        viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 255);
        viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
        viewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        viewController.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }];
```

I tried to do the same thing in swift:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        vc.view.superview?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 255)
        vc.view.superview?.center = self.view.center
        vc.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        vc.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The problem with this code is that my view frame open in a full screen mode instead of opening with the set size (200x255).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work on ipad but not iPhone?

Comment: This code works in iPhone and iPad (The name "PopoverChoiseTableViewController" is a name of my class) but I present this view as Modal View Controller.

Comment: this is not positioning centre. Do you have any idea?